# Fill in column based on previous value in R

Tags: r

I am looking for a tidyverse solution to the following problem.

I have the following example dataset:

```
ex_tbl <- tibble(col1 = c(5, NA, NA, NA), col2 = c(1, 1.3, 0.8, 1.2))
```

I need to fill in the NAs based on col2 and the previous value in the col1. If I start with the first NA (col1, row 2), and col2 is greater than 1, then I'd multiply the previous col1 value (row 1) by col2 row 2. Then if col2 is less than or equal to 1, then col1 is just equal to the previous value.

This should be the final result:

```
  col1  col2
     5   1  
    6.5  1.3
    6.5  0.8
    7.8  1.2
```

I tried `case_when()` but am not getting the desired result:

```
output <- ex_tbl %>% mutate(col1 = case_when(col2 > 1 ~ col1 * col2,
                                              col2 <= 1 ~ col1,
                                              TRUE ~ col1)
```

Clearly, I'm not capturing the part where I want to use the previous row's value. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could use

```r
library(dplyr)

ex_tbl %>% 
  mutate(col1 = first(col1) * cumprod(pmax(col2, 1)))
```

to get

```r
# A tibble: 4 x 2
   col1  col2
  <dbl> <dbl>
1   5     1  
2   6.5   1.3
3   6.5   0.8
4   7.8   1.2
```

#### Edit: Follow-up question

If you want to multiply by a value from a third column in case of `col2 < 1`, you could use:

```r
ex_tbl <- tibble(col1 = c(5, NA, NA, NA), col2 = c(1, 1.3, 0.8, 1.2), col3 = c(0.5, 2, 2, 0.3))

ex_tbl %>% 
  mutate(
    factor = (col2 >= 1) * col2 + (col2 < 1) * col3,
    col1 = first(col1) * cumprod((col2 >= 1) * col2 + (col2 < 1) * col3))
```

Note: the column `factor` here isn't necessary. It's just to show what is happening inside the `cumprod` function.

Comment: Thanks, this is a great answer! I have a follow up question if my question gets a bit more complicated.

Can we still use cumprod if:
- When col2 > 1, multiply the previous col1 value (row 1) by col2 row 2. 
- When col2 <= 1, then multiply previous col1 by a value in a third column.

Comment: @H.Cahill See the edit.

Comment: This is a clever solution, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

We may need `accumulate` here

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
ex_tbl %>% 
   mutate(coln = accumulate(col2, ~  if(.y <= 1) .x else .x * .y , 
         .init = first(col1))[-1])
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 × 3
   col1  col2  coln
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     5   1     5  
2    NA   1.3   6.5
3    NA   0.8   6.5
4    NA   1.2   7.8
```

Comment: This is a great answer as well, thank you!